# ROS universal directory defintion

Tags: python, git, directory, ros, universal

I am working with executable files that are to be included in the main node file. But the problem is that although I can define the path in my PC and open a text file with or execute the file but it is not universal with my other team members which are part of the team. The have to change the code after pulling from git.

I have the following commands:

```
    os.chdir( "/home/user/epsilon/epsilon_catkin_ws/src/knowledge_source/sense_manager/pddl_files/")

    os.system("./ff -p /home/user/epsilon/epsilon_catkin_ws/src/knowledge_source/sense_manager/pddl_files/ -o domain.pddl -f problem.pddl >

    solution_path = "/home/user/epsilon/epsilon_catkin_ws/src/knowledge_source/sense_manager/pddl_files/solution.txt" solution_detail.txt")
```

Since the path are unique with my laptop, it will require changes by everyone. IS there a way to make the path definition universal? (The commands are part of the service call that is present in that node). I am using rosrun to run the node

I tried the following pattern but it does not work:

```
    os.chdir( "$(find knowledge_source)/sense_manager/pddl_files/")
```

Do I need to do something extra to make this work?
**knowledge_source** is the name of the package

Any recommendations?

Comment: You give it as a command line argument, which (optionally) defaults to the current directory.

Comment: What do you mean? i tried the following as well ..... did not work

Comment: solution_path = "~/epsilon/epsilon_catkin_ws/src/knowledge_source/sense_manager/pddl_files/solution.txt"

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for rospkg and os combination to get the path to a file inside a ros package.

```
import rospkg
import os
conf_file_path = os.path.join(rospkg.RosPack().get_path('your_ros_pkg'), 'your_folder_in_the_package', 'your_file_name')
```